# mootools addEvent for calling 2 functions?

Tags: mootools, mootools-events

My problem is that I'm trying to call 2 functions in my addEvent, but it's not possible I think. I am developing a forum,  and one of that function is for the subforum, and the other are for answers, all I want to do It is that when I press that link the link fetch all the php in a div or two div and paste the results in that.
Is it possible? Is there a better way?

```
$$('a.hrefMosRBT').addEvent('click', 
    function(){
        mostrarTemaRespuesta(this.get('id'),mostrarSubTemasDelBuscado(this.get('id')))
    }
);
```

Comment: Ehm, what's wrong about calling the 2 functions sequentially inside the callback? Does the first one (mostrarTemaRespuesta) contains asynch stuff?

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to tell what your functions do, but what is the problem with simply doing?

```
$$('a.hrefMosRBT').addEvent('click', function(){
    mostrarTemaRespuesta(that.get('id'));
    mostrarSubTemasDelBuscado(that.get('id'));
});
```